# Как исключить символ из группы?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Нужно выбрать все небуквенные символы кроме пробела

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/[^A-z\s]+/ui
```

Comment: извините, неправильно вопрос задал)

Comment: Поправил. Исключаем буквенные и пробельные символы.

Comment: ничего не выделяет, c#

Comment: Поправил и проверил. Попробуйте так :)

Comment: по прежнему пусто) ну да ладно, нашел другой способ - \p{P}